# R: How to Convert the Conversational Questn Answer Pattern into Data Frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, corpus, tm

I have read the following text file and have following problem,

---

Filename: QnA.txt

---

Question: What is your name?

Answer: XXXX

Question: Please tell me your address?

Answer: XXX, xxxx-ssss, 00000

Question: Tell me other details

Answer: sure, ................

---

```
txt <- "directory path"
QuesAnsFiles <- Corpus(DirSource(txt, encoding = "UTF-8"),readerControl = list(language = "lat"))
```

I have read this text file in corpus, and now I have to do some text mining in that file, for which I have to create each corpus file into a dataFrame like:

```
df <- data.frame(Question='',Answer='')
```

How could I read each corpus and convert into the data frame of my desire...?

**More Description for Understanding:**

**df$Question** will show all the question, and correspondingly **df$Answer** shows the answer of the corresponding question

Kindly suggest the approperiate way to do comeover this problem, later i'll focus on the speed also...

Answer (score 2):

Read the file into a character vector with `readLines`, then use regular expressions to extract the parts that you need.

```
library(stringr)
lines <- readlines("your file")
questions <- str_match(lines, "Question: (.*)")[, 2]
answers <- str_match(lines, "Answer: (.*)")[, 2]
data.frame(
  Question = questions[!is.na(questions)],
  Answer   = answers[!is.na(answers)]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [qdap version 1.1.0](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/qdap-1-1-0-released-on-cran/) to accomplish this task readily.  First qdap has the `read.transcript` function that reads the transcript data you have.  Then with a reordering and `sentCombine` we can combine by person:

```
dat <- read.transcript(text="Question: What is your name?
Answer: XXXX
Question: Please tell me your address?
Answer: XXX, xxxx-ssss, 00000
Question: Tell me other details
Answer: sure, ................", col.names =qcv(person, text))


with(dat[order(dat$person), ], sentCombine(text, person))

##     person                                                   text.var
## 1   Answer                     XXXX XXX, xxxx-ssss, 00000 sure, .....
## 2 Question What is your name? Please tell me your address? Tell me...
```

Also note that [qdap version 1.1.0](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/qdap-1-1-0-released-on-cran/) added a number of functions to integrate with the tm package.  See [`?tdm`](http://trinker.github.io/qdap/tdm.html) for more.

Also I read the data in directly here.  In reality you'd want to use `read.transcript("directory path")`.  This works with txt, csv, xlsx and docx files.